# Missing context for method declaration?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an app and when I added this IBAction, it gave me the error Missing context for method declaration. I have looked up how to fix this but I am a bit confused since I am a beginner. The errors appear in my .m file:

```
#import "QRscannerSecondViewController.h"

@end

@interface QRscannerSecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation QRscannerSecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Info", @"Info");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

-(IBAction)button1
{
[input resignFirstResponder];
l11 = input.text;
line11.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", l11];
}
```

but I though that it would help if I included my .h file, also.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QRscannerSecondViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface TextGameViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UITextField *input;
IBOutlet UILabel *line11;
NSString *l11;
}
-(IBAction)button1;
```

Comment: you would not put the implementation of the method _outside_ of the `@implementation` scope, it also would be great you to use the standard `-(IBActon)button:(id)sender;` scheme instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the code:

```
-(IBAction)button1
{
[input resignFirstResponder];
l11 = input.text;
line11.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", l11];
}
```

before the `@end`.